# is it dangerous to open the DVD rom?

Tags: dvd

I have a Lenovo G510 laptop with Windows 8.1. Its more than a year old and out of warranty. Earlier its DVD ROM used to work fine, but sometime back, we started watching a TV series which involved playing a lot of DVDs over last few months. After that what we have noticed is that a lot of DVDs/CDs which used to work earlier, are not working anymore, they don't even appear in the "My computer" page anymore which seems like not being detected any more. The CDs/DVDs are fine, almost brand-new, so no scratch issue. I want to open the DVD ROM up and clear/clean the eye(this is the term i heard people used on some websites). But somewhere also read that there is a possible radiation danger, esp. (or only?) when laptop is powered on? Does someone have more information whether there really is a radiation danger in the laptop powered off state? the label does not provide this detail - it only says laser radiation danger. Please help, i don't want to spend money on a new external hard drive if this one can be clean repaired. At the same time i don't want to expose myself to radiations for saving few bucks. Thanks!

Comment: Probably a really gentle cleaning of the dvd unit lens would bring it back to life. Also, dust likes to accumulate in the optical block (there are more lenses that are not visible), I use to really gentle blow a bit of compressed air into the mobile assembly. Emphasis on really gentle. Laser is off when tray is open.

Comment: The laser in an optical drive is considered [Class 3B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety#Class_3B) and can be dangerous *if energized*. However, **it won't work if disconnected from power** and it should contain safety interlocks that prevent the laser from engaging if the drive is open even if powered on.

Comment: Thanks Dan and DragonLord, so do you think using something like a hair dryer (on mild setting) to push the dirt out, should work?

Comment: Clean it with a cotton bud with the laptop powered off and see what happens. If that doesn't work it's cheap to get replacement drives from your favourite auction site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it dangerous to open the DVD rom?

> I want to open the DVD ROM up and clear/clean the eye (this is the term I heard people used on some websites)

The "eye" is actually a lens.

Rather than open up the DVD drive to clean the lens it is better (and safer) to buy a specialised cleaning product. They are not very expensive.

They consist of a CD that has special brushes attached that will clean the lens when you "play" them for a short time.

Here are some examples:

[Memorex CD and DVD Lens Cleaning Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008EM7U)

> - 6 ultra soft brushes
> - Helps maximize performance.
> - 7 sound optimization tools on the disc.
> - Removes dust from the lens of a CD and DVD player
> - Seven sound optimization tools help optimize the sound quality of your stereo system
> - Includes 6 brushes remove dust and dirt

[Maxell DVD-LC DVD Lens Cleaner - Blue](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000JPPI)

> - Designed for DVD players
> - Features Thunderon Brush System
> - Equipment set up and enhancement features (ideal for home theater)
> - Interactive on-screen instructions with 8 languages

You can find many more examples by searching for "dvd lens cleaner"