# How to diagnose and interpret CD-R burn error codes coming from iTunes on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, compact-disc, burning, cd-r

I’ve been trying to burn a bunch of CD-Rs in iTunes on Windows 7 and it seems like every time I get a different error (e.g. 4000, 4261, 4880, etc.).

Unfortunately everything I search for online is vague, “Yahoo! Answers” type stuff with suggestions like “reinstall iTunes” and doesn’t actually pinpoint the problem.

Is there a list of error codes with description that can help me diagnose what the issue might be?

Are error codes specific to each device, or are there standard error codes? A way to check what the sub-error code is for more information?

Comment: Trying using another program such as **cdburnerxp**  Then there is this  list of error codes.  https://cdburnerxp.se/help/references/errorcodes

Comment: Have you tried burning at a lower speed? Also don't use the really cheap brands of CD-Rs ... I've had those before and had to discard a whole pack ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, lower speed does seem to help, but I don't now... I've been gradually backing it off more and more, I'm down to 8x from 24x now.

Comment: Have you also tried cleaning your DVD drive? See [is it dangerous to open the DVD rom?](http://superuser.com/a/943038) for more info.